# Calling an (instance) method from another class

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, methods

the way to call a method has driven me really crazy! and unfortunately I couldn't find it in the questions already asked.
I know how to alloc and init
but the thing is in my program I need to call the method inside its own class 
here is a sample implementation, of course I know I could do this in dozen simpler ways but in the program I develop I have a much complex case that I need to do in this way

in my NIB file I have a label, and two buttons. 
the label and one of the buttons (called "set to today") are linked in appDelegate
the other button (called "set to ten days later") is linked to classTwo
here are the codes for all the files
although the code doesn't produce any error, but triggering the second button has no effect
what is the proper way to call that method.

AppDelegate.h:

```cpp
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
    NSDate *toDay;
}
-(IBAction)setToToday:(id)sender;
-(void)updateLabelText;
-(void)setToTenDays;

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```cpp
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
-(IBAction)setToToday:(id)sender
{
    toDay=[NSDate date];
    [self updateLabelText]; 
}
-(void)updateLabelText
{
    [label setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",toDay]];
}
-(void)setToTenDays
{
    int secondsPerDay=60*60*24;
    toDay = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:10*secondsPerDay sinceDate:toDay];
}
@end
```

ClassTwo.h

```cpp
@interface ClassTwo : NSObject
-(IBAction)setToTenDaysLater:(id)sender;
@end
```

ClassTwo.m

```cpp
#import "ClassTwo.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation ClassTwo
-(IBAction)setToTenDaysLater:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *classOne=[[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [classOne setToTenDays];
    [classOne updateLabelText];
}
@end
```

Why I can't get the label set to new date?
both of the objects are in NIB file and actions and outlets are set
Thank you in advance for you kind helps.

P.S. in my real experience , for example I am using a trackpad event in CustomWindow Class to change the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in class two, you're creating a new instance of AppDelegate, not calling the already-created one. You're only supposed to have one NSApplicationDelegate anyway.

You need to set up a reference to ClassOne from ClassTwo in the header file and connect them in the NIB, or set it programmatically, if you're creating ClassTwo programmatically.

Edit: I've added property accessors, make sure to read up on [declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).

```
@class AppDelegate;

@interface ClassTwo : NSObject {
   AppDelegate *delegate;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet AppDelegate *delegate;

- (IBAction)setToTenDaysLater:(id)sender;

@end
```

ClassTwo.m

```
#import "ClassTwo.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation ClassTwo

@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction)setToTenDaysLater:(id)sender {

    [delegate setToTenDays];
    [delegate updateLabelText];
}
@end
```

Then in ClassOne (AppDelegate) You could just set the `delegate` property like so:

```
classTwo.delegate = self;
```

Where `classTwo` is an IBOutlet to an archived instance in your XIB, or you could create it in code as well.

Comment: Wow! thanks, that worked! could you please help with setting delegates programmatically?

Comment: It's just a matter of adding a property to your ClassTwo instance and setting it up in code, which I've added above.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayView *year = [[DisplayView alloc] initWithNibName:DisplayView bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:year animated:YES];
```